# only the bottom line is executed

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`indexno`, email, name, day) "
    . "VALUES ('$indexno', '$email', '$username', '$dday');";   
        $sql = "update countd set countd = countd + 1 where day = 'monday'";
```

only the bottom line  of the code is executed.when I removed the bottom line the top line is executed without an issue. should I write both the lines in the same SQL variable if so could you post the syntax. Thank you

Comment: You need add more code for this question

Comment: You overwrite the content of `$sql` in the second line, assuming that `$sql` is executed after these two lines, it obyiously only executes the second line, with is currently stored in `$sql`. You need to execute `$sql` after both assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make two $sql as $sql1 and $sql2 and then execute them separately.

Here you are reseting then value of $sql in second statement.

Comment: feel free to accept by clicking on the check button fro appreciation .

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`indexno`, email, name, day) "
    . "VALUES ('$indexno', '$email', '$username', '$dday');"; 
  
 $sql2 = "update countd set countd = countd + 1 where day ='monday'";

Comment: it worked before but now only the top line is executed pls help

Answer (score -1):

you actually re-assign your variable before you execute the statement inside it.

you have several solution to fix your problem

- Create two separate variable : $sqlInsert and $sqlUpdate and give different statement inside your different variable
- Create an array with your statements

First solution

```
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO users (`indexno`, email, name, day) "
. "VALUES ('$indexno', '$email', '$username', '$dday');";   

$sqlUpdate = "update countd set countd = countd + 1 where day = 'monday'";    

$mysql->request($sqlInsert);
$mysql->request($sqlUpdate);
```

Second solution

```
$sqlStatements = [
    "INSERT INTO users (`indexno`, email, name, day) . "VALUES ('$indexno', '$email', '$username', '$dday')",
    "update countd set countd = countd + 1 where day = 'monday'"
]

foreach($sqlStatements as $sqlStatement) {
    $mysql->request($sqlStatement);
}
```

Last thing, be careful about giving variables inside sql statement you potentially run into sql injection attack

Answer (score -1):

Make two separately $sql with different name and then execute your bottom line.

i think there is no issue found .